# MYSQL won't start Post 3306 in use

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, xampp

```
00:33:43  [mysql]   Problem detected!
00:33:43  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL"!
00:33:43  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
00:33:43  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
00:33:43  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
00:33:43  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

Error after downloading MySQL server and mysql for visual studio

Edit: Now it says Attempting to start MySQL app... and then it keeps loading and won't open after switching port to 3307

Comment: that probably because more mysql services using the same port , check for active program that using that port, you can try to type this in "netstat -ano | findstr :3306"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably an easier fix:

1) Open Commandline -> type: "netstat -aon"

2) Check out the PID on port 3306

3) Go to Task Manager and stop the process with that PID

4) Restart XAMPP and retry MySQL

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop the xampp server, if it is already running.
2. Edit the value to "port" in xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini

code:

```
     Password = your_password   
     port =  3306  --->  3307  
     socket =  "/ xampp / mysql / mysql.sock"
```

and here also

Code:

```
     The MySQL server 
     [ mysqld ] 
     port =  3306  --->  3307 
     socket =  "/ xampp / mysql / mysql.sock"
```

3. Restart

Comment: What's the recent my.ini file?

Comment: if you are using xampp, go to xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini

Comment: i changed the port from 3306 to 3307 there but it still gives me the same error. thanks for the help btw

Comment: Thanks! and what about the php.ini file?

Comment: did you restart? try running under administration

Comment: yes, that is what i mean... this above must have worked.. try changing the port on php.ini from 

mysqli.default_port=3306 --> 3307

check if port 3307 is also available or not from netstat that is integrated on the xampp.